# Wrong password creating on first boot (cloud-init) (Ubuntu 20.04 server, RPI 4)

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, password, user, init

I try create preinstalled user for Ubuntu 20.04. For this i add some entries in accordance with official docs, to */etc/cloud/cloud.cfg* (config for cloud-init )
Old:

```
users:
   - default
```

My:

```
 users:
   - default
   - name: myuser
     groups: myuser
     home: /home/myuser
     shell: /bin/bash
     hashed_passwd: $6$1234567890ABCDEF$3ytr6BmrrL5SVyQFBeHLveNX5ublgYVM8Cae3AS2g1gNsZgzenAKUzfvYRUGOIUk4YX5c6qngE5cx.JaiFe/k1
```

And next run on raspberry pi 4. After finish initialization (without errrors ) i try login on user and this step failed. After i see on /etc/shadow for check password creation, and find this line

*/etc/shadow:*

```
myuser:!$6$1234567890ABCDEF$3ytr6BmrrL5SVyQFBeHLveNX5ublgYVM8Cae3AS2g1gNsZgzenAKUzfvYRUGOIUk4YX5c6qngE5cx.JaiFe/k1:18717:0:99999:7:::
```

And seed reduntant '!' on password's begin. Without this '!' all worked good.

How can i fix this trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this one got me as well its because of the following parameter and its default settings;-

```
lock_passwd: Optional. Disable password login. Default: true
```

So the fix is to set `lock_passwd: false` in your 'users' section as the default is to lock the password by prefixing a '!'